# writing file using File.WriteAllBytes giving error while accessing file created by this function

Tags: c#, web-services, web

I have used the following code and it works fine. But sometimes it throws an exception:

```
Message :- The process cannot access the file   'DownloadDB\client\user\filename.db' because it is being used by another process.

Stack Trace :- 
at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalExtract(String baseDir, Stream outstream,    String password)
at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Extract(String baseDirectory)
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile._InternalExtractAll(String path, Boolean overrideExtractExistingProperty)
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ExtractAll(String path, ExtractExistingFileAction extractExistingFile)
at ecpMobileToWebSync.UnZipFiles(String strZipFilePath, String CombinePath, String fk_EmpGLCode)
```

My code is given below:

```
    private string SyncDB(string FileArray)
    {
        string pathNew = "";
        byte[] encodedDataAsBytesSyncDB = System.Convert.FromBase64String(FileArray);
        pathNew = Server.MapPath("~/SyncDB/" + strClientName_File + "/" + UserName + "/" + Filename);
        File.WriteAllBytes(pathNew, encodedDataAsBytesSyncDB);

        byte[] encodedDataAsBytesDownloadDB = System.Convert.FromBase64String(FileArray);
        pathNew = Server.MapPath("~/DownloadDB/" + strClientName_File + "/" + UserName + "/" + Filename);
        File.WriteAllBytes(pathNew, encodedDataAsBytesDownloadDB);

        encodedDataAsBytesSyncDB = null;
        encodedDataAsBytesDownloadDB = null;
        FileArray = null;

        string strFileName = string.Empty;
        if (File.Exists(pathNew))
        {
            strFileName = UnZipFiles(pathNew, Server.MapPath("~/DownloadDB/" + strClientName_File + "/" + UserName + "/"));
        }

    }
    private string UnZipFiles(string strZipFilePath, string CombinePath)
    {
        string strZilEntryFileName = string.Empty;
        ReturnData objReturnData = new ReturnData();
        objReturnData.isValid = true;
        objReturnData.Message = "";
        try
        {
            using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(strZipFilePath))
            {
                strZilEntryFileName = zip1.Entries.Single().FileName;
                var flattenFoldersOnExtract = zip1.FlattenFoldersOnExtract;
                zip1.FlattenFoldersOnExtract = true;
                zip1.ExtractAll(CombinePath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                zip1.FlattenFoldersOnExtract = flattenFoldersOnExtract;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogDetails.LogException(this.GetType().Name.ToString(), System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString());
            objReturnData.isValid = false;
            objReturnData.Message = MsgException_Failure;
        }
        return strZilEntryFileName;
    }
```

In this code I am getting a byte array of a zip file from a client and then I am performing reverse engineering for converting the byte array to the zip file and then extracting it.

First I will call the SyncDB function with the byte array and then calling UnZipFiles for unzip the file.

It's all working fine but in some cases it will give an exception.

Comment: What exception does it give?

Comment: when i call function UnZipFiles()  from SyncDB fuction it will throw exception in UnZipFiles() function. exception is : The process cannot access the file   'DownloadDB\client\user\filename.db' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Not when does it give an exception _what exception does it give_?

Comment: i have already given message and stack trace of exception at top of my question

Comment: Can it be that user do 2(or more) request nearly instantly? I think it will be visibile from logs.

Comment: this procees is carried out from android device so while processing user can not made second request unless and untill the first request is serverd.  if user do it second time then new file will be created with time ticks appeand to filename